# AlertDialog inside a for loop

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am creating a simple image app and I am having trouble renaming the images
The user selects multiple images in the gallery and click a button to rename them all. the class responsible for the renaming operation and is where I am having trouble.

The first part of the code is as follows:

```
class RenameFiles {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<CreateList> Images;
    private ArrayList mSelectedItems;
    private int RenameAppendCounter = 0;
    private boolean DecisionForAll = false;
    private String RenameConflictDecision = "";
    private String[] RenameArray_State;
    private File[][] RenameArray_Files;

FileSystemClass(Context context, ArrayList<CreateList> InputImages) {
    mContext = context;
    Images = InputImages;
    RenameArray_State = new String[InputImages.size()];
    RenameArray_Files = new File[InputImages.size()][2];
    mHandler = new Handler();
    Rename();
}

private void Rename() {
    String DialogBoxTitle = "Rename";
    String DialogBoxMessage = "Enter new name";
    final AlertDialog.Builder DialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    DialogBox.setTitle(DialogBoxTitle);
    DialogBox.setMessage(DialogBoxMessage);
    final EditText UserInput = new EditText(mContext);
    UserInput.setInputType((InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT));
    DialogBox.setView(UserInput);
    final boolean[] ConflictFlag = {false};
    DialogBox.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            File imgFolder = new File(String.valueOf(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)));
            for (int i = 0; i < Images.size(); i++) {
                String NewFileName = UserInput.getText().toString();
                if (RenameAppendCounter > 0) {
                    NewFileName = NewFileName + " (" + String.valueOf(RenameAppendCounter) + ")";
                }
                File NewFile = new File(imgFolder, NewFileName + ".png");
                File OriginalFile = new File(Images.get(i).getImage_path());

                if (NewFile.exists()) {
                    RenameArray_State[i] = "Conflict";
                    ConflictFlag[0] = true;
                    RenameArray_Files[i][0] = OriginalFile;
                    RenameArray_Files[i][1] = NewFile;
                    RenameAppendCounter = RenameAppendCounter + 1;

                } else {
                    RenameArray_State[i] = "Write";
                    RenameArray_Files[i][0] = OriginalFile;
                    RenameArray_Files[i][1] = NewFile;
                    //  RenameOperation(OriginalFile,NewFile);
                    RenameOperation(OriginalFile, NewFile);
                    RenameAppendCounter = RenameAppendCounter + 1;

                }
            }
            if (!ConflictFlag[0]) {
                for (int i = 0; i < RenameArray_State.length; i++) {
                    RenameOperation(RenameArray_Files[i][0], RenameArray_Files[i][1]);
                }
            } 
            else {
                OverwriteSkip();
            }
            dialog.dismiss(); 
        }
    });
    DialogBox.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    DialogBox.show();
}
```

The main arguments to the class is context and "InputImages". "InputImages" is an ArrayList which contains the selected images ID, title, path and bitmap. The ArrayList "Images" is basically "InputImages"
The user enters the name and all files are renamed to the user selected name after incrementing the file name. So basically if the user enters "name" the files are renamed to "name.png", "name (1).png", "name (2).png" and so on

The main method is "Rename()" which is basically an alertDialog that requires the user to enter the new name.  Once the user clicks "OK", the method loops through "Images" ArrayList and populates two arrays, a multidimensional array "RenameArray_Files" and "RenameArray_State". "RenameArray_Files" contains the OriginalFile and the NewFile, and "RenameArray_State" contains one of the three states, "Write", or "Conflict". "Write" is basically change the name of the file, "Conflict" means that the file name already exist and in such cases the flag "ConflictFlag[0] is set

Once the ArrayList is looped through completely, if there are no conflicts ("Conflictflag[0]" is not set), the method "RenameOperation" is called and all files are renamed.

if there is a conflict, the method "OverwriteSkip" is called. The idea is for the user to decide whether to overwrite a file, skip it, (or later on, rename it but not there just yet). the user can also select whether their decision applies to all files or just the one.

```
      private void OverwriteSkip() {
        for (int i = 0; i < RenameArray_State.length; i++) {
            final File OriginalFile = RenameArray_Files[i][0];
            final File NewFile = RenameArray_Files[i][1];
            if (RenameArray_State[i].equals("Conflict")) {
                if (DecisionForAll && RenameConflictDecision.equals("Overwrite")) {
                    RenameArray_State[i] = "Write";
                    RenameOperation(RenameArray_Files[i][0], RenameArray_Files[i][1]);
                } else if (DecisionForAll && RenameConflictDecision.equals("Skip")) {
                    RenameArray_State[i] = "Skip";
                    RenameOperation(RenameArray_Files[i][0], RenameArray_Files[i][1]);
                } else if (!DecisionForAll) {
                    final int finali = i;
                    String ConflictingFileName = NewFile.getName();
                    String[] Choices = new String[1];
                    Choices[0] = "Apply to all conflicts";
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                    builder.setTitle("File '" + ConflictingFileName + "' already exists");
                    mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();  // Where we track the selected items
                    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(Choices, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                                mSelectedItems.add(which);
                            } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                                // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                                mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Overwrite", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            RenameConflictDecision = "Overwrite";
                            DecisionForAll = false;
                            if (mSelectedItems.size() == 1) {
                                DecisionForAll = true;
                                RenameConflictDecision = "OverwriteAll";
                            }
                            RenameArray_State[finali] = "Write";
                            RenameOperation(OriginalFile, NewFile);
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Skip", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            DecisionForAll = false;
                            RenameConflictDecision = "Skip";
                            if (mSelectedItems.size() == 1) {
                                DecisionForAll = true;
                                //      RenameConflictDecision = "SkipAll";
                            }
                            RenameArray_State[finali] = "Skip";
                            //        RenameAppendCounter = RenameAppendCounter + 1;
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
            }
            else {
                RenameOperation(RenameArray_Files[i][0], RenameArray_Files[i][1]);
            }

        }

    }

    private void RenameOperation(File OriginalFile, File NewFile) {
        OriginalFile.renameTo(NewFile);
    }
}
```

OverwriteSkip loops through "RenameArray_State", once a conflicting file is reached, and the user has not set the flag to apply to all conflicts yet, a second alartdialog will be displayed asking the user to either overwrite or skip the file. A checkbox to apply decision to all conflicts will also be available. If this checkbox is clicked, the next conflict will automatically have the decision be applied to it.

The issue is that the second alert does not popup until the for loop is completely iterated. I understand that the reason behind it so that the alert dialog does not keep the system busy and impeding other operations. But I am not sure how to run this logic. I read that I need to implement a second thread where the second alert dialog is displayed but I am not sure how to do that, I am new to Android and Java so I could use help please! I am open to other ways of doing this other than a second thread!
I will pay with words of praise and nude pics (I am lying..no nudity, just praise and appreciation)

Answer (score 0):

```
mForloop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                        openAlertDailog();

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where do I put this? what view am I listening to?